# matlab block averaging time series data

Tags: matlab

Q:**MATLAB RELATED:** Can someone help me with a MATLAB code for block averaging of time series dataset? Also how do I determine the optimal number of blocks

Background:I have a large time series dataset (position versus time) which I break into 20 smaller blocks. I need to find the variance of position for each block. Since there is a possibility that there is autocorrelation of data, normal averaging doesn't work for me, and I would need to perform block averaging.

Comment: What are your problems implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `reshape` command followed by a `mean` and/or `var` (for average or variance)

At the MATLAB terminal, type:

```
help reshape
```